# I deleted the Ubuntu partition from Windows 7, now I can't access Windows

Tags: windows-7, delete, partitioning

I deleted the partition containing Ubuntu from my computer -- manage -- disk management 
and now my laptop is showing:

```
error: no such partition.
grub rescue> 3
```

Please tell me how can I open my regular Windows 7 now.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure of this, but you could try those steps:

1. Install Ubuntu again in the same partition you installed the deleted one.
2. Install [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) in the installed Ubuntu

   1. Open the Terminal
   2. Run this command to add the ppa that contains Boot-Repair:

      `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair && sudo apt-get update`
   3. Run this command to install Boot-Repair:

      `sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)`

After that: perform the "Recommended repair" (a topic at the link above)

> ## Recommended repair
>
> 1. launch Boot-Repair from either :
>
>    1. the Dash (the Ubuntu logo at the top-left of the screen)
>    2. or System->Administration->Boot-Repair menu (Ubuntu 10.04 only)
>    3. or by typing 'boot-repair' in a terminal
> 2. Then click the "Recommended repair" button. When repair is finished, note the URL (paste.ubuntu.com/XXXXX) that appeared on a
>      paper, then reboot and check if you recovered access to your OSs.
> 3. If the repair did not succeed, indicate the URL to people who help you by email or forum.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible in that installing Ubuntu after Windows you replaced the windows boot manager with GRUB and therefore when you removed Ubuntu you damaged/removed GRUB files which only allowed you to access the GRUB menu you're presented with.

Try running the Windows 7 repair disc and accessing the CMD. From there try:

```
 bootrec /fixboot
```

And

```
bootrec /fixmbr
```

Your best bet is with the `/fixmbr` as it simply repairs the master boot record.